# Is it correct to say "To draw C. Start at the top, and go around to the left till you reach the bottom."?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage

I am teaching my 4.5 year-old kid to **write letter C.**

[image]

I copied this phrase from a video on youtube. Probally, the video is made by native English speakers.

Watch [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDkGR6Bl6Ao) starting at **3:40**

"**I start at the top, and go around till you reach the bottom.**"

My question is that

If we say that, then it can be either one of the 2 symbols shown in the above picture.

Do we need to add "**to the left**" to make it clearer?

For example, "**To draw C. Start at the top, and go around to the left till you reach the bottom.**"?

**Note**: The key point is to tell the child to make **a smooth movement** and **a minimum effort** without having to lift the pen and using an eraser.

Comment: Yes, "to the left" makes things clearer, I suppose, but it's not at all clear anyway if you're not watching the video, and if you *are* watching the video, you don't need the extra words (or really any words) to see how to draw the letter.

Answer (score 1):

The C starts going to the left, but ends going to the right. A clearer way to explain it to an adult would be:

> To draw C, start at the top right, and go anti-clockwise until you reach the bottom right.

This might not work with a young child, who may never have seen an analogue clock, and even then may not know which way the hands move.

Comment: "**anti-clockwise**" is good but do we need to say "**go around anti-clockwise...**" or just  "**go anti-clockwise...**"?

Comment: You would have to say "go around" if there were something in the middle of the C. There is nothing in the middle of the C, so "go anti-clockwise" is fine.

Answer (score 0):

"to the left" is ambiguous, maybe:

> To draw C, draw a semicircle on the left side without the line

If that's too complicated:

> To draw C, start at the top, draw a line **curving to the left**

It may be confusing to young kids, but it might work.